# Is it possible to impersonate a user in wso2 , if so how to implement it?

Tags: wso2, impersonation

Is it possible to impersonate a user in wso2. When I searched for the possibilities I have arrived at this issue posted on GitHub - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5443

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature is not available in the product out of the box. But custom solutions can be implemented using the available extensions.

Found following on the public web

- https://dinushad92.medium.com/how-to-impersonate-someone-else-using-wso2-identity-server-part-1-a26b6685f141
- https://www.yenlo.com/blogs/impersonating-user-in-identity-server/